# Why is it displaying as "Projects origin/master" beside the project name in STS4

Tags: git, spring-boot

I am getting "Projects origin/master" beside the project name in STS4, what might be the reason?

[image: screenshot]

[image: Screenshot git status]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsKLz.png): [GIT Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsKLz.png)

Comment: Looks like the branch that is checked out there (`origin/blahblah` being a remote branch).

Comment: You need to provide details on which program the screenshot is taken from. Without that information it will make no sense to the wast majority of people reading this question. And please also inline the picture.

Comment: Hi @hlovdal it's a SpringBoot application program and I am using Springtool Suite 4

Comment: Hi @eftshift could please share the steps(I mean GIT commands which I need to execute) to get out this problem.

Comment: I think it's better you put the output of `git status` from that project in the question (**as text**) and tell us what is wrong and what you want from there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @eftshift0 I have added the GIT Status Screenshot please look into it and help me to not get the [Projects origin/master] text beside the Project name in SpringTool Suite 4

Comment: Ok... so... you are in _detached HEAD state_ working on top of `origin/master`.... I see nothing out of the ordinary there and I think it makes sense for Eclipse (?) to show you so. What would you like to see instead? (as a side note, could you replace the image for text?)

Comment: @eftshift0 if you observe my first image there is project called as Eureka Server and side note just a [boot] as it is a SpringBoot application So I want to see that and I want to know what are the problems I will face if HEAD is in detached state